# How to resolve cascade deleting in Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have three entities. The first one is Company entity (see below).

```
@Entity
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Employee> employees;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    private List<HistoryRecord> historyRecords;
```

The second is Employee

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Integer id;

    @Column
    String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = true)
    private Company company;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
    private List<HistoryRecord> historyRecords;
```

Here is my HistoryRecord class

```
@Entity
public class HistoryRecord {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    Employee employee;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    Company company;

    @Column(name = "hire_date")
    Date hireDate;

    @Column(name = "resign_date")
    Date resignDate;
```

When I'm trying to execute delete operation on Employee I'm getting this error

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [delete from employee where id=?]; constraint [&quot;CONSTRAINT_12: PUBLIC.HISTORY_RECORD FOREIGN KEY(EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.EMPLOYEE(ID)
```

I think the problem is in cascade operation but I'm not sure. Is anybody can say how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the relationship of Employee -- HistoryRecord.  The employee property on HistoryRecord is not nullable.  If you want the HistoryRecord to be deleted when an employee is being deleted you need to add the cascade attribute to the @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee") for historyRecords on Employee.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee",cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The ENDDM generates

```
ALTER TABLE "public"."project_group" ADD CONSTRAINT "mandant" FOREIGN KEY (mandant_id) REFERENCES "mandant" ("mandant_id") ON DELETE CASCADE DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

for the database and

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
```

in Java.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update your relation mapping in Company class is is missing cascade.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<HistoryRecord> historyRecords;
```